# How to properly render a success message upon clipboard click and copy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, html5-clipboard-api

I'm creating a color palette where I have a clipboard icon within a Tooltip component next to each color. On click it will copy the color's name onto the user's clipboard. When that happens, the Tooltip's message should change from "copy" to "copy success". I'm having issues trying to display the success message individually for each color.

Answer (score 0):

All of you `Tooltip` components are using the same parent state `this.state.copyMessage`. If you click copy on one, that sets `this.state.copyMessage` to `"copy success"`, and it gets rerendered for all other Tooltips. You need to be able to either:

1. identify who was clicked,
2. give state to each Tooltip,
3. add one state entry per tooltip.

I'd personally go with a way to identify who was clicked.

Global declaration

```js
const PROMPT_MESSAGE = "Copy to clipboard"
const CLICKED_MESSAGE = "Copied!"
```

Set your state onClick

```js
setState({ clickedColor: color.name });
```

Get the appropriate message for the specific color

```js
const tooltipTitle = this.state.clickedColor === color.name
  ? CLICKED_MESSAGE
  : PROMPT_MESSAGE
```

Pass in the title

```js
<Tooltip title={tooltipTitle} placement="right">
</Tooltip>
```

There are many ways to work around this, and this is just one I find readable!

Comment: ah ok, now the tooltip messages change but the first onclick trigger doesn't work on the first click. I have to click twice to see "copy success"..

Comment: @darz123 I'm not exactly sure what the cause would be. I think you should try setting the initial state to `initialState = {clickedColor: ""}`. I'm inclined to say this is a quirk of styleguidist.

Comment: @darz123 I also noticed that you are missing the `key` prop. When building a list of components with a function like `.map` you should pass in `key={something unique}`. In this case, you can (probably) use `color.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 'event' as a parameter to your onClick function and using the stopPropagation() method. Like so:

```
<Tooltip title={copyMessage} placement="right">
      <span
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation()
          copyNameToClipboard(color.name);
          setState({
            copyMessage: 'copy success',   
          });
        }}
      >
```

This should stop your event from 'bubbling up' to other components:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation